# Having trouble reformatting date

Tags: python, date, datetime, format

I have a dict that has a bunch of dates in European format `(%d/%m/%Y)`. 
I am trying to reformat the dates so that they are in US format `(%m/%d/%Y)`.
Whenever I run it, the following error is identified:

```
ValueError: time data '2' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'
```

Anyone know what I need to correct? 
Thanks for your help!

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
from time import mktime


Transaction_Date=[
"23/08/2017",
"23/08/2017",
"21/08/2017",
"01/10/2017",
"19/08/2017",
"19/08/2017",
"18/08/2017",
"03/09/2017",
"27/09/2017",
"26/08/2017",
"03/10/2017",
"27/09/2017",
"27/03/2017",
"02/08/2017",
"20/08/2017",
"20/08/2017",
"20/08/2017",
"20/08/2017",
"20/08/2017",
"20/08/2017"]

for row in Transaction_Date:
    Transaction_Date = row[0]
    Transaction_Date = datetime.strptime(Transaction_Date,'%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    print(Transaction_Date)
```

Gives the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'
```

From what I can tell, the dates format is correct, why is the system saying different?

Comment: Don't take the 0th index of `row`. So, use `row` not `row[0]` which is picking the first character of each string.

Comment: Please also fix your code formatting. I can't do it for you as I'm on phone. Highlight your code block and click the `{}` button in the editor, or use ctrl+k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `row` inside your loop as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

Transaction_Dates = [
    "23/08/2017", "23/08/2017", "21/08/2017", "01/10/2017",
    "19/08/2017", "19/08/2017", "18/08/2017", "03/09/2017",
    "27/09/2017", "26/08/2017", "03/10/2017", "27/09/2017",
    "27/03/2017", "02/08/2017", "20/08/2017", "20/08/2017",
    "20/08/2017", "20/08/2017", "20/08/2017", "20/08/2017"]

for row in Transaction_Dates:
    print(datetime.strptime(row, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Which displays:

```
08/23/2017
08/23/2017
08/21/2017
10/01/2017
08/19/2017
08/19/2017
08/18/2017
09/03/2017
09/27/2017
08/26/2017
10/03/2017
09/27/2017
03/27/2017
08/02/2017
08/20/2017
08/20/2017
08/20/2017
08/20/2017
08/20/2017
08/20/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 mistakes:-

Using same name (`Transition_Date`) for both collection and your result,
you are using `row[0]` instead of `row`

```
from datetime import datetime 
import time 
from time import mktime

Transaction_Date_Collection = [ "23/08/2017", "23/08/2017", "21/08/2017", "01/10/2017", "19/08/2017", "19/08/2017", "18/08/2017", "03/09/2017", "27/09/2017", "26/08/2017", "03/10/2017", "27/09/2017", "27/03/2017", "02/08/2017", "20/08/2017", "20/08/2017", "20/08/2017", "20/08/2017", "20/08/2017", "20/08/2017"]

for Transaction_Date in Transaction_Date_Collection: 
    Transaction_Date = datetime.strptime(Transaction_Date,'%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    print(Transaction_Date)
```